# How can i get a bitrate of video/audio using HTML5/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I want to write function to return a bitrate of video/audio ( screen size, resolution). how should we implemented this ?

Comment: you don't need to put a full stop after a question mark :-/